# Union tables in Vertica SQL where tables have different order of columns?

Tags: sql, union, vertica

I have 2 tables in Vertica SQL and how can I union all these tables to create tables as in result ? As you can see tables 1 and table 2 have different order of columns:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEmEu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just list the columns in the order you want them:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from table1
union all
select col2, col1, null
from table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SELECT INTO and UNION ALL would solve your problem

```
SELECT * INTO TEMP TABLE RESULT FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```